# como que uso o ActionListen? presciso de um exemplo pra entender melhor

Tags: java, swing, javafx, gui, awt

Galera, em uma pergunta anterior eu tinha feito uma pergunta sobre actionListen, mas eu queria vim pedir um exemplo, alguém poderia me dar um exemplo, criei esse simples codigo q mostra um JButton no Swing, queria q alguem me desse um exemplo tipo...demonstrando onde deveria colocar o actionListen para abrir outra JFrame

simples codigo que criei:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class inicio{

    public static void main(String[] args){

       JFrame frame = new JFrame("Tela de incio");
       JPanel painel = new JPanel();
       JButton confirm = new JButton("CONFIRMAR");
       frame.add(painel);
       painel.add(confirm);
       confirm.setBounds(10,10,10,10);
       frame.setSize(600,600);
       frame.setVisible(true);


    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Olá @joaoazevedo, vou te explicar da minha forma resumida como funciona e dar um exemplo de ActionListener.

Então, o ActionListener é um código que permite dar uma ação a um objeto...
Por exemplo aqui eu defini que a variavel 'sair' vai ter uma ação de dar um 'exit' na programação.

- ActionListener = cria uma lista de eventos para o objeto.
- ActionEvent = cria o evento da lista da variavel e dentro do evento
  se coloca a sua respectiva ação...

  ```
  sair.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          System.exit(0);
      }
  });
  ```

Aqui vou colocar minha programação por completa se quiser copiar e fazer seus testes na sua IDE.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class telaPrincipal extends JFrame{
private Container c1;
private JButton sair, inicio;
private ImageIcon img1;
private JLabel imgfundo, logo;
Quiz frame = new Quiz();

public telaPrincipal() {
    inicializarComponentes();
    definirEventos();
}

private void inicializarComponentes() {
    setLayout(null);

    c1 = getContentPane();
    getContentPane().setBackground(Color.black);
    img1 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("telaprincipal2.gif"));         
    imgfundo = new JLabel(img1);

    inicio = new JButton("Iniciar");

    sair = new JButton("Sair");
    sair.setMnemonic('S');

    logo =  new JLabel("QUIZ PROGRAMER FOR PROGRAMERS");
    logo.setForeground(Color.white); 
    logo.setFont(new Font ("SansSerif", Font.ITALIC, 50));
    logo.setBounds(5,20,1500,60);

    inicio.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 60));
    inicio.setForeground(Color.white);
    inicio.setOpaque           (false);
    inicio.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    inicio.setBorderPainted    (false);

    sair.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 60));
    sair.setForeground(Color.white);
    sair.setOpaque           (false);
    sair.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    sair.setBorderPainted    (false);
    imgfundo.setBounds(0,20,960,740);
    inicio.setBounds(360,260,250,80);
    sair.setBounds(360,460,250,80);
    add(logo);
    add(inicio);
    add(sair);
    add(imgfundo);
}
public void definirEventos() {
    sair.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });

    inicio.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //Quiz p1 = new Quiz();
            //p1.validate();
            //c1.add(p1);
            //c1.removeAll();
            //c1.validate();
        } 
    });
}

public static void main(String args[]) {

    telaPrincipal frame = new telaPrincipal();
     frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     frame.setUndecorated(true);
     frame.setBounds(200,0,960,740);
     frame.setVisible(true);

  }
}
```

*Espero muito ter ajudado, se estiver com duvidas não exite em perguntar.*

Comment: alias, aqui neste código ele chama outro JFrame.                                             
    inicio.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {...});

Comment: ah vlw...mas enquanto eu estava pensando eu criei outra dúvida, tipo tem como eu criar um programa o da tela de login por exemplo, e colocar caso clique no botão abrir outro programa .java?

Comment: sim sim @ joaoazevedo, por exemplo o meu botão de 'inicio' você mudaria ele para 'login', e dentro dele você chama a tela normalmente como eu fiz e na tela a ser chamada você coloca sua "aplicação".